# How to write stateful dbus methods in haskell?

Tags: haskell, dbus, state-monad, reader-monad

I'm working with [dbus](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.3/package/dbus-0.10.15) in haskell, and I'm having difficulties figuring out how to export dbus methods that perform stateful operations. Below is a fully fleshed out example to illustrate where I'm stuck.

---

Let's say you're writing a counter service with dbus. When the service starts, the counter is initially at 0. The service defines a dbus API that exposes a `count` method, which returns the current value of the counter, and an `update` method, which increments that counter, and returns the new value.

Here's a pseudocodey implementation of the behavior I just described, using a message-passing-style of communication:

```hs
-- | Updates the given integer. 
update :: Int -> Int
update = (+1)

-- | main function with message-passing-style communication
mainLoop :: Int -> IO Int
mainLoop state = do
  case receiveMessage of
    "update" -> do -- increment / update counter
      sendReply $ update state
      mainLoop $ update state -- recurse
    "count" -> do -- return counter value
      sendReply state
      mainLoop state
    "stop" -> do -- stop the counting service
      exitSuccess

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mainLoop 0
```

However, dbus uses method-calls, not message passing. So, I need to be able to [export](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.3/dbus-0.10.15/DBus-Client.html#v:export) a `count` and `update` method that behaves the same way as in my message-passing example.

The stub we'll work with is something like this:

```hs
-- | Updates the given integer. 
update :: Int -> Int
update = (+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let initialState = 0
  dbus <- connectSession
  export dbus "/org/counter/CounterService"
    [ autoMethod "org.counter.CounterService" "update" ({-- call update? --})
    , autoMethod "org.counter.CounterService" "count" ({-- return state? --}) ]
```

And here lies my question: **How should I encode the missing `{-- call update? --}` and `{-- return state? --}` functions?**

I know I can use an `MVar` to create global mutable state, and then just make the functions read from that, but I want to avoid mutability as much as possible here. I *think* I can do this with the Reader/State monad somehow, maybe by sneaking a `get`/`ask` into the functions, but I don't know how to handle the types with respect to DBus.

Comment: When interfacing with other languages, one must often do non-idiomatic things. Your `MVar` idea is the exact right tack; go for it.

Comment: There's no point in "avoiding mutability". There *is* a point in *separating* mutability from mutability. If you want to use `State`, then write a some kind of `runStateOn :: State s a -> MVar s -> IO a` and do as that type implies.

Comment: Hmm, the warp whispers `unliftio` to me. Maybe you should try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the `dbus` package only allows you to `export` methods of [type `Method`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.27/dbus-1.2.16/DBus-Client.html#t:Method), which has a `methodHandler` field that returns the monadic value:

```
DBusR Reply === ReaderT Client IO Reply
```

and there's no room in there for you to squeeze in your own `StateT` monad.  You could export [a `Property`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.27/dbus-1.2.16/DBus-Client.html#t:Property) instead, but that doesn't help you, since the fields of that type also involve `IO` actions to get and set the property.

So, maintaining your state in `IO`, most likely as an `MVar`, is going to be pretty much unavoidable.

You could try to separate your pure-ish "core" from the IO shell.  One way to do it (as per @HTNW's comment) is to write the core in `State`:

```
type Counter = Int

update :: State Counter ()
update = modify (+1)

count :: State Counter Int
count = get
```

and lift it to `IO` with something like:

```
import Data.Tuple (swap)

runStateIO :: State s a -> MVar s -> IO a
runStateIO act s = modifyMVar s (return . swap . runState act)

main = do
    ...
    s <- newMVar 0
    let run act = runStateIO act s

    export dbus "/com/example/CounterService"
      defaultInterface
      { interfaceName = "com.example.CounterService"
      , interfaceMethods =
        [ autoMethod "update" (run update)
        , autoMethod "count" (run count) ]
      }
```

(I think I'm using a newer version of `dbus` here than you, since the API is a little different -- I'm testing with `dbus-1.2.16`, FYI.)

One potential drawback is that this is going to lock the state `MVar` on every method call, even if the call doesn't need the state or needs only read-only access.  DBus services are typically pretty low-traffic with method calls that are intended to complete quickly, so I don't think this is a problem in practice.

Anyway, a here's a full working program, which I tested with:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=com.example /com/example/CounterService com.example.CounterService.update
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=com.example /com/example/CounterService com.example.CounterService.count
```

The program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import System.IO
import System.Exit
import Data.Int
import DBus.Client
import Data.Tuple
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad.State

type Counter = Int32

update :: State Counter ()
update = modify (+1)

count :: State Counter Int32
count = get

runStateIO :: State s a -> MVar s -> IO a
runStateIO act s = modifyMVar s (return . swap . runState act)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dbus <- connectSession

  requestResult <- requestName dbus "com.example" []
  when (requestResult /= NamePrimaryOwner) $ do
    hPutStrLn stderr "Name \"com.example\" not available"
    exitFailure

  s <- newMVar 0
  let run act = runStateIO act s

  export dbus "/com/example/CounterService"
    defaultInterface
    { interfaceName = "com.example.CounterService"
    , interfaceMethods =
      [ autoMethod "update" (run update)
      , autoMethod "count" (run count) ]
    }

  forever $ threadDelay 60000000
```